# building an application with curllib

Tags: c++, macos, libcurl

I've build openssl, libssh2 and libcurl on mac os 10.8
When I try to link libcurl with my application I get the following errors

> /usr/local/include/curl/curlrules.h:143:6: '**curl_rule_01**' declared
>   as an array with a negative size
>   /usr/local/include/curl/curlrules.h:153:6: '**curl_rule_02**' declared
>   as an array with a negative size

I found out that it is related to the conflict between already installed curl and new one.
What is the best workaround to resolve it?

Comment: I resolved it just redefining CURL_SIZEOF_CURL_OFF_T and CURL_SIZEOF_LONG from 8 to 4

Comment: Thanks for commenting back here, saved me many hours :)

Answer (score 0):

That's the result of a broken install of the curl headers. I'd recommend re-running configure to get a fresh set of headers to use.